# compile error: expected end of statement

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

A Microsoft Access 2010 database is giving me the following error message:

```
Compile Error: Expected End Of Statement
```

Here is the method that is throwing the error message:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    'Provide the user with the option to save/undo
    'changes made to the record in the form
    If MsgBox("Changes have been made to this record." _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to save these changes?" _
        , vbYesNo, "Changes Made...") = vbYes Then
            DoCmd.Save
        Else
            DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
    End If

    Dim sSQL As String
    sSQL = "SELECT max(Clients.ClientNumber) AS maxClientNumber FROM Clients"
    Dim rs As DAO Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
    MsgBox ("Max client number is: " & rs.Fields(1))
End Sub
```

The line of code that is throwing the error message is:

```
 Dim rs As DAO Recordset
```

I am not sure if the problem has to do with the syntax of what is on the line preceding it.  Can anyone show how to fix this problem?  And explain what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a full stop (period) between the `DAO` and the `Recordset` - it should be

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
```

Beyond that, you will also have a runtime error on reading the field value, since a DAO Fields collection is indexed from 0, not 1. Hence, change the penultimate line to this:

```
MsgBox ("Max client number is: " & rs.Fields(0))
```

Alternatively, reference the field by its name:

```
MsgBox ("Max client number is: " & rs!maxClientNumber)
```

Comment: No, that wasn't my suggestion - read it again... Use *either* `rs.Fields(0)` *or* `rs!maxClientNumber` - your `rs!Fields(0)` is a muddle.

Comment: If anyone is wondering that was a reply to a comment that's now been deleted, though the point still stands (you can't index by position using the bang operator)...

Comment: That was not the problem.

Comment: @CodeMed - what wasn't the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're mising the semicolon at the end of your Sql statement